# Mxgraph how to export JSON data files

Tags: mxgraph

I found under the mxgraph GitHub source files exported XML file function is wrong, I would like to have a direct export of JSON data files

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the XML of the graph by downloading xmlToJSON.js from https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON.

Be sure to include this in your HTML file with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xmlToJSON.js"></script>
```

From there, the following code snippet should convert your XML to JSON

```
function parseXmlJSON (model)
        {
            var encoder = new mxCodec();
            var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());

            var testString = mxUtils.getXml(node);   // fetch xml (string or document/node)
            var result = xmlToJSON.parseString(testString);   // parses to JSON object
            mxUtils.popup(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4), true); // turns into string
        }
```

Feel free to replace mxUtils.popup with console.log or alert etc.